# How to vectorise/speed up grouping/filtering data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with a "ID", "status", and "age" columns. A particular ID has several rows in the data frame, some of them have status 0 while some have status 1. I want to

1. Filter out ALL rows of those ID's which have no rows with status 1. For example if ID 5673 has ten rows with status 0 but no rows with status 1 -> all rows with ID 5673 have to be removed.
2. Group the entries by ID, and perform aggregate sum of the "age". For example, if ID 9873 has one row with status 1, and five rows with status 0 -> The final dataframe should contain only one row for ID 9873, and the column of SUM(age), should contain the sum of all fifteen age entries in the original dataframe for ID 9873.

I could probably do this with a for loop and all, but I've seen several answers saying that it is inefficient and not recommended with pandas. Instead, I am looking for a fast vectorized implementation using some inbuilt function like group by. My dataframe has more than 10^5 rows, so speed might be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Try using masks:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html

```
mask = df["ID"] == 1
print(df[mask])
```

For aggregation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

You can combine it with masks.